# Why does Symfony 2 use app_dev.php instead of one front controller?

Tags: symfony

Coming from ZF background I was quite surprised to see Symfony's app_dev.php file. It seems like a very bad idea security-wise. It's one more step you need to take to make sure your dev is not accessible in production. I.e. you can't have simple Git deploy, unless you don't mind having dev version on production or have post checkout hook to remove the file or specific vhost setup that disables access to it.

What is the idea behind it? Why is it better than IP-triggered or ENV based dev mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue [#677](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/677) discussing why it's this way. There are also some interesting comments in related issue [#11310](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11310#issuecomment-48086337).

The most reasonable argument for me is that it just works out of box without the need to setup environment variables or anything else. Although counterargument is that you still need to setup htaccess rewrite anyway.

Comment: To make even more clear - it is the `symfony-standard` that uses that. And the `symfony-standard` is just an opinionated implementation on how to bootstrap the symfony framework.

Comment: Just a note: since Symfony 4, there will be only 1 controller: http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-best-practices.html, seek: "Unified Web Front Controller"

Answer (score 1):

First off all, there is no real "production" and "dev" modes per se. They are just named that way. You could easily use other modes, each with their own set of configurations which are loaded through `config_<env>.yml` for instance. Actually, there is a third standard mode called "test" which is reserved for testing Symfony.

Second, it's very easy to test things in "production" mode and "development" mode by simple add `app_dev.php` in between your url. This will make it easier to look at how your app actually looks like in production, without losing all the nice things like verbose logging and the web debug toolbar.

And as stated: by default the `app_dev.php` frontend uses by default a whitelist so even if you happen to push this file onto production, they would not be able to view it).

There are other reasons for multiple entry points: as an Symfony application can contain multiple applications at the same time. By default, `app.php` and `app_dev.php` are the front controllers for the default application, but it might be possible (quite easily actually) to have an `admin.php` and `admin_dev.php` as well, bootstrapping a whole different application, while still being part of the same repository (if this is a wise thing to do, is up for debate).

Answer (score 0):

if you look into app_dev.php file, you can see that only whitelisted IP addresses have access to app_dev.php file.

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Comment: but still, why two files instead of setting $dev=true if the above condition matches?

Comment: Because it makes app.php and app_dev.php cleaner.  Why add extra conditional code that runs on every request in production it you don't need to?  If app_dev.php offends you then modify app.php to use an env variable and delete app_dev.php.  Symfony 2 has been released for about 5 years now.  Not aware of any exploits caused by app_dev.php..